# How can I use decoded JSON data inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, json, wavesurfer.js

Using [this](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) plugin I need to draw an audio waveform with pre-rendered data.

I stored JSON data inside MySQL as `{"sample_rate":44100,"samples_per_pixel":4410,"bits":8,"length":2668,"data":[0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11,0.13,0.13,0.24,0.35 ...]}`

So I tried:

**PHP**

```
$json = $row['wave'];
$json_array = json_decode($json);
$json_wave = implode(',', $json_array->data);
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-track-wave="'.$json_wave.'" id="play'.$row['id'].'" class="track"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function createWaveform(json) {
    $( "#waveformbottom" ).empty();
    var linGrad = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0,0,0,170);
    linGrad.addColorStop(0, '#ff3b25'); 
    linGrad.addColorStop(0.5, '#ff0018'); 

    var wavesurferbottom = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: document.querySelector('#waveformbottom'),
        waveColor: '#b3b3b3',
        progressColor: linGrad,
        backend: 'MediaElement',
        mediaType:'audio',
        height:'48',
        cursorColor:'#fff',
        cursorWidth:'0',
        normalize:true,
        barWidth:'2'
    });

    //Set peaks ! THE PROBLEM !
    wavesurferbottom.backend.peaks = [json];
    //Draw peaks
    wavesurferbottom.drawBuffer();

    $(window).resize(function(){
       if($(this).width() != width){
            widthbottom = $(this).width();
            wavesurferbottom.drawer.containerWidth = wavesurferbottom.drawer.container.clientWidth;
            wavesurferbottom.drawBuffer();  
       }
    });
}

$(document).on('click touchend', '.track', function(e) {
    var wave_data = $(this).data('track-wave');

    createWaveform(json);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

A debug of my `wave_data` shows that is correct like `0.01,0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11,...` however the waveform is not drawn.

Instead if I set `wavesurferbottom.backend.peaks = [0.01,0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11,...];`it works.

I'm not a JSON expert, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `0.01,0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11,...` isn't JSON

Comment: btw. why you call an array something that is an object ($json_array) ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I wrote JSON decoded...look at the top of the question `... $json_wave = implode(',', $json_array->data);`

Comment: `[json]` where `json` is the string `'0.01,0.13,...'` gives you an array with a single element: `['0.01,0.13,...']`. You'll probably want to `split` that string into an array…

Comment: @SimonLeCat .. php's implode function does not produce JSON, it produces a simple string

Comment: @JaromandaX the JSON is stored in MySQL

Comment: @SimonLeCat - yes, but you say the JSON is correct, then produce a string that is in no way JSON

Comment: $json is JSON, $json_wave is not

Comment: you don't need to edit the question, you need to understand what you've done incorrectly ... you've taken a presumable JSON string, converted it to a PHP array, and then converted that to a simple string of elements joined by a `,` ... use $json where you now use $json_wave, and you need to JSON.parse this string in javascript in the createWaveform function ... `wavesurferbottom.backend.peaks = JSON.parse(json);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that one is a string (which isn't valid JSON anyway - it's just a list of comma separated numbers):

> data-track-json="0.01,0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11"

```
var json = $(this).data('track-json'); // a string
```

And the other is a JS array:

```
var x=[0.01,0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11];
```

A simple approach is to split it by `,` - that'll convert your string into the JS array that you need, like so:

```
var samples = $(this).data('track-json').split(','); // Renamed because it's not JSON
..
createWaveform(samples);
```

It's also worth noting that you'll get an array of *strings* rather than an array of numbers, but many JS libraries handle that. If you wanted to go the JSON route, then make sure your attribute contains square brackets:

> data-track-json="[0.01,0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11]"

The PHP to create that could look like this:

```
$json_wave = '['.implode(',', $json_array->data).']';
```

Then use a JSON.parse call to convert it into a suitable array of number types:

```
var samples = JSON.parse( $(this).data('track-json') );
```

Comment: Encoding json with implode and concatenating with leading and trailing square brackets doesn't sound right IMO. There is the json_encode(), so that you get valid JSON in all cases, to mention just the associative arrays, indexed arrays, objects.

Comment: @jakubwrona I've never been a fan of json_encode on the basis of reliability; [like many other things in PHP](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/), it might 'accidentally' output an assoc JSON object when you really wanted an indexed array.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use JSON

**PHP**

```
$json = $row['wave'];
$object = json_decode($json);
$json_wave = json_encode($object->data);
```

This is a JSON string, presumably something like `[1,2,3,4]`

**HTML** unchanged

```
<div data-track-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-track-id="'.$row['id'].'" data-track-json="'.$json_wave.'" id="play'.$row['id'].'" class="track song-play-btn playthistrack"></div>
```

**JS** parse the JSON where you've identified the problem

```
//Set peaks ! THE PROBLEM !
wavesurferbottom.backend.peaks = JSON.parse(json);
```

`wavesurferbottom.backend.peaks` will be an array of Numbers - presumably what the rest of the code expects

Comment: Inside MySQL the JSON string is like `{"sample_rate":44100,"samples_per_pixel":4410,"bits":8,"length":2668,"data":[0.01,0.01,0.01,...` and I'm using the data object

Comment: do you need the sample_rate etc, or just `data`

Comment: I didn't notice the ->data in the original question, sorry - edited